# CSSSelector unable to locate element with name parameter

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have one page with 5 buttons and I need to find button with Name " Search "(with both leading and trailing whitespace)

When I try both these(printing name just for testing purpose) :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.gxi-button")).get(1).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.gxi-button[name=' Search ']")).getText());
```

for first command its reutrning text " Search " but for second command its throwing exception " org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here. Its seems that leading and trailing space is causing issue here. Can anyone guide how to deal with this?
Note: I have tried with both ' Search ' and 'Search' and in both case getting same exception

Comment: "I can see some whitespace in front of "Search". Is that is causing the problem" - well, haven't you tried?

Comment: What if you use double rather than single quotes in the selector?  `By.cssSelector("a.gxi-button[name=\" Search \"]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `*=` to perform a partial matching.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.gxi-button[name*='Search']")).getText());
```

Or use XPath (if above still doesn't work)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@class='gxi-button' and contains(@name, 'Search')]")).getText();
```

Or use XPath's `normalize-space` function

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@class='gxi-button' and normalize-space(@name)='Search']).getText();
```